# How can i create a variable in R that is dependent of two other variables, and must have a certain value?

Tags: r, variables, mutate

```
db %>% 
  mutate(esc=ifelse((fn<100) | ((fn>100 & tt < 20) | (fn <300 & tt < 20)), "Yes", "No")
```

In my database I want to make a variable 'esc', which is dependent of the values of fn and tt. I want the esc to be Yes or No, and it should be yes in case fn is below 100 OR fn is above 100 while tt is below 20 OR fn is below 300 while tt is below 20. However, I receive the following error:

> Error: unexpected symbol in: "  mutate(esc=ifelse((fn<100) | ((fn>100
> & tt < 20) | (fn <300 & tt < 20)), "Yes", "No") db"

Does anyone have any advice for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please provide an example of your data? PS: I think you are missing a parenthesis `)` at the end, try this: `db %>% mutate(esc = ifelse((fn<100) | ((fn>100 & tt < 20) | (fn <300 & tt < 20)),"Yes", "No"))`

Comment: The `" db"` in the error message is strange, are you sure the code here is the same you are running?

Comment: @RuamPimentel I double checked and you were right about the parenthesis! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that no more than one alternative is true suggest minor change:

```
db %>% 
  mutate(esc=ifelse((fn<100) | ((fn>100 & tt < 20) | (fn <300 & tt < 20)), "Yes", "No")
         
db %>%
  mutate(esc=ifelse((fn<100) | (fn > 100 & fn < 300) & tt < 20)), "Yes", "No")
```